# C# filepath from fileuploader fails to be read by streamreader asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, relative-path, streamreader

Running into an issue with a streamwriter

I have a web page that has a FileUploader in a loginview to access it I am using

```
var fileuploader = (FileUpload)LoginView.FindControl("FileUploader");
string filepath =  System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fileuploader.FileName.ToString());
```

Then I pass that data in to my streamreader which is (in a different class)

```
 using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
```

The filepath that it is passing in is C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\sample.txt

Where I am selecting it from C:\fasta\sample.txt

I have seen some posts about this, but not concerning asp.net applications.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the SaveAs method on the FileUpload control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx).

Remember, the file is actually uploaded to you, and from a website, you'll never really want to care about the location it was at on the client machine (it just so happens the server and client are the same machine for you here).  If you uploaded the file to the site from a different machine, the web server would never have access to the resource at the client's path.  The FileUpload control has the file for you, so just take the file, place where you want, and then you can access it and do whatever you want with it.

Cliffs: even if you get the client path to the resource, your server won't be able to do anything with it since it is on another machine which your server doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 2):

The [**FileUpload**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) class allows **a client to upload/select a file**. So all you can get would be a **clientPath**. Such a path would of no need to you! So what you can do is using the `fileUpload.FileName` property and *combine it with some other path.*

```
var fileuploader = (FileUpload)LoginView.FindControl("FileUploader");
string filepath =  Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), fileuploader.FileName);
fileuploader.SaveAs(filePath); // will save the selected file on your server
```

[**Server.MapPath(..)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) maps a virtual path (at the server) to a real path at your server. Calling it with `"."` means this call will return *your webApplication root directory*. Anyway you should **be very careful when uploading files** where to save those! In worst case someone uploads a potential risky file (eg .aspx extension) and can execute code on your server!

Furthermore there is no need and *no way to access a file at the client from the server directly*. You may only get those items within the HTTP-Request. So the *selectedFile is already in the Request* and you can save it directly to your server harddisk!

Comment: while this gets me the path of where the web form is located, it doesn't get me the address of where the user has the file.

Comment: see updated question on how to save the file on your server without using a streamreader!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the file uploaded:

**.aspx**

```
...
<asp:FileUpLoad id="FileUpLoad1" runat="server" />
...
```

**code-behind**

```
...
if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
{
    FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\" + FileUpLoad1.FileName);
}
else
{
   // No file uploaded
}
...
```

---

If you want the file path, the one that client had set in the browser control:

**You can't**. For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path.